# Why getting uri' must not be empty using JAXB in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, soap-client

I am trying to consume SOAP Web Services in Springboot. so i am trying to hitting the request from SOAP UI and gettingthe error as below:

i have provided the Server point even getting the below error.

Error:

> 2018-06-12 15:40:03.725  INFO 2028 --- [nio-8088-exec-1]
>   o.s.w.s.s.SaajSoapMessageFactory         : Creating SAAJ 1.3
>   MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'uri' must not be empty   at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.hasLength(Assert.java:233)    at
>   org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:547)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383)

Please find the code as below:

```
public class UserClientConfig extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public UserListResponse getUserList(UserList request) {

        UserListResponse response = (UserListResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(   //here getting  uri' must not be empty
                request, new SoapActionCallback("http://*.*.WebServices/Services/UserList"));
        return response;
    }
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"COM.*.*.Services"})
public class WSConfigClient {
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("http://*.*.WebServices/Services");
        return marshaller;
    }
    @Bean
    public UserClientConfig UserClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        UserClientConfig client = new UserClientConfig();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://....:8090/");//Server endpoint
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
} 


@Endpoint
public class UserClientEndpoint {

    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(UserClientEndpoint.class);



    UserClientResponse response = null;

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = CteConstants.NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "UserClient")
    @ResponsePayload
    public UserClientResponse UserClientRequest(@RequestPayload UserClient request) throws Exception {

    try {

                UserClientConfig client = new UserClientConfig();

                response = client.getUserList(request);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return response;
    }
```

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Hi , What was issue in this case ? .. How you resolved this ?